# Java - can't change int value inside for-each loop

Tags: java, foreach

This question looks hilariously obvious, however I can't see my fault...
I'm declaring an int variable inside for-each loop and it looks like I can't modify it.

```
for(String tmp : list) {
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        i++;
}
```

List is a LinkedList that is not empty and exists somewhere in the code. The output is:

```
i = 0
i = 0
i = 0
```

Is it even possible to modify a value of int inside such loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With each loop, you create a **new** `i` variable, one completely unrelated to the previous ones from previous iterations of the loop. Solution: declare it above the loop.

```
int i = 0;
for(String tmp : list) {
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the declaration of `int i = 0` outside the for loop. Currently you are just initializing an `int i` to `0` every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit it, but the variable is discarded after the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

It should be outside the for loop

```
int i = 0;
for(String tmp : list) {
    System.out.println("i = " + i);
    i++;
}
```